# git housekeeping on forked repository and local branches

Tags: git, github, build, build-automation

Just need some suggestion /advise on below scenario please
In our company, we have github implemented and as part of our defect fix or enhancement in our development process.

1. We fork git repository to each developer id
2. Create new branch based on defect/enhancement id
3. Fix/implement in this local repo/branch and test it. Once tested
4. We raise pull request
5. Administrator reviews the pull request and merge the changes.
6. And so on.

But I noticed, we leave the forked repository and branch created (for fix/enhancement) I don’t see we perform any housekeeping to delete these repo/branches.
Please advise the best practice and the workflow for housekeeping
Also how to automate the analysis and get report?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick answer about cleaning up branches. Remember, the branch exists both locally and on the forked remote.

- Delete the branch on the remote fork through GitHub.com (or your company's access site).
- Delete the branch locally: `git branch -d <branch-name>`.
- Update the local repository and get rid of the remote tracking branch: `git pull --prune`.

However, there's a bigger question about workflow. Do you delete the fork every time you merge a branch, then re-fork when you start a new branch? Could your team instead let you branch on the same repository and give you collaborator access?